# Returning either a JSP view or a plain message on a Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

On the same controller handler method, I would like to either:

- return a JSP view when the request is valid
- set the appropriate HTTP status code and just write a simple String message to the Response body if the request is not valid

Is this possible with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(ModelMap model, 
                    HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (isValidAsYouWant(request)) { // check validity 
         // setup reference data

        return "viewName";

    } else {
        response.setStatus(400);
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("Invalid Request");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;           
    }
}
```